# How to get touch events in Chrome Dev Tools 64

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

There are a couple of answers but it's too outdated. There is also a [post](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/) says default Responsive Mode would simulate touch event, but when I run some thing like

```
window.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
 console.log(e)
})
```

it still logs e as a Mouse event, which means `touchstart` is captured, but event is a mouse event, and it doesn't make any sense.

So how do I get Touch event?

Comment: I'm getting `TouchEvent` logged to the console when I turn on Mobile mode in DevTools. See https://i.imgur.com/fusoH8P.png

Comment: @GideonPyzer thanks! This is so weird, I just tried and it worked too. I guess maybe there is other events on my dev app.